# Definition of 'Scramble Road'

Tags: translation, culture

I was watching an MMD on YouTube called '[Tokio Funka](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZAN8ZuGQ4g)' created by PizaCG and quite enjoyed the fact that they included an English language translation in the Closed Captions.  I was able to lookup most of the song references but was stumped by 'Being able to enjoy the Scramble Road is alright'.  It could be a miss-translation or a very obscure reference.  I would appreciate it if someone could provide an explanation or determine if there is a better translation.

Thanks

Comment: At least you should make a link to the point in time which the sentence appears at.

Comment: And the actual lyrics would help too https://vocaloidlyrics.fandom.com/wiki/%E3%83%88%E3%82%AD%E3%83%B2%E3%83%BB%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AB_(Tokio_Funka)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 賭博構想　お上は焦燥
>   洒落では済まぬお目こぼし横行
>   スクランブル往来 楽しめりゃalright
>   お前は一体この先どうしたい？

The song is set in an imaginary city with a mixed modern Japanese and old Ōedo culture. This スクランブル往来 is a unique made-up word made of modern and old words.

This スクランブル refers to スクランブル交差点 (Wikipedia: [Pedestrian scramble — In Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedestrian_scramble#In_Japan)) found in modern big cities. Shibuya's scramble crossing is one of the best-known and it's sometimes seen as a symbol of modern Japan. 往来 is an old word for road/street. 交差点/道路 might have sounded "too modern" because this city may not even have cars or electricity.

**EDIT:** 往来 in modern Japanese usually means "traffic", but as pointed out in the comment, 往来 also used to mean "street". I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: 今気づいたのですがもしかして「往来」のtrafficって「車の往来が激しい」とかの意味ですか？これはこれで「人の行き来するところ=道路」の意味があり近世の口語では普通この意味で使われます。

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth 確かに。直しました、ありがとうございます。